# Calculate surface area of batch reactor

Tags: chemical-engineering, process-engineering

I have calculated the volume of reactor for 30000 tpa product also its diameter and height and its volume is 86 kL.

**How to calculate the surface area of the same reactor to check requirement of heat?**
*If possible please provide references regarding the same.*

Comment: surface area of many shapes are known - sphere? cube? box?